# Forms of list initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initializer-list, list-initialization

See the following code:

```
std::vector<int> v1{1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> v2 = {1, 2, 3};
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a difference between the two? I know the first one must be list initialization, but how about the second?
2. Because there is a assign sign for the second, it makes me think that the compiler will use the `std::initializer_list` to create a temporary `vector` first, then it use copy constructor to copy the temp `vector` to `v2`. Is this the fact?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two ([*direct-list-initialization* vs *copy-list-initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)) are exactly the same in this case. No temporary `std::vector` is constructed and there's no `std::vector::operator=` called. The equals sign is part of the initialization syntax.

There would be a difference if [`std::vector`'s constructor overload no. 7](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) was marked `explicit`, in which case any *copy-initialization* fails, but that would be a flaw in the design of the standard library.

Comment: So both the two belong to list initialization, they have no association with the copy initialization, right ?

Comment: *copy-list-initialization* is defined in terms of *copy-initialization*. I've used *copy-initialization* just to generalize a bit.

Answer (score 8):

They're both [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11). The first one is direct-list-initialization, and the second one is copy-list-initialization.

> 1. Is there any difference between the two?

For direct-list-initialization both explicit and non-explicit constructors will be considered, while copy-list-initialization only non-explicit constructors might be called. For this case (i.e. `std::vector`) the actual result is same.

> 2. Because there is a assign sign for the second, it makes me think that the compiler will use the initializer_list to create an temp vector first, then it use copy constructor to copy the temp vector to v2. Is this the fact?

No. Even for the copy-list-initialization, the object will be constructed by the appropriate constructor directly. For this case, a temporary `std::initializer_list<int>` will be created and then `std::vector::vector(std::initializer_list<T>, const Allocator& = Allocator())` will be called to construct `v2`.

Comment: It's interesting to add that in C++17, it could be different if you use auto and a list with only one element.

Comment: @AntonioGarrido no it wouldn't. `auto v = {1}` never ever deduced a `std::vector`. Indeed now it will deduce `int` instead of `std::initializer_list`, but is completely irrelevant to the discussion about `std::vector`.

Comment: @AntonioGarrido if you want to bring C++17 and auto into discussion, it may be somewhat relevant that you will be able to write `auto v = vector{1, 2, 3}` (template deduction for constructor)

Comment: @bolov IMHO, it is relevant. In the answer is somewhat expressed that using = or not is only relevant with respect to the implicit/explicit construction, but in C++17, another aspect is added: it is not the same. See, for example, "C++ type deduction and why you care" Scott Meyers, slide 20. Your line about template deduction for constructor is not related with this discusion (this discusion, in this answer, where direct-list-initializacion vs copy-list-initialization is discussed). In any case, I clicked the flag of your comment. I like people to remember me my lack of precision. Thanks!

Comment: @AntonioGarrido just pure curiosity: what kind flag have you raised with my comment?

Comment: `Type val = { ... };` and `Type val { ... };` are exactly the same in any case.

Comment: @AndreiR. No, they're not same in some cases. I've explained it in my answer, you might point out where I'm wrong.