# removing double elements in an array

Tags: c++

I am trying to remove double elements in an array. I developed a simple code, but it is still not working. Is it possible to hint for some input maybe I haven't tried. I tried corner and test cases. The following is the problem statement:

A sequence of numbers given. Remove element’s doubles, leaving first copy.

Input: Contains a natural n (n ≤ 100000) – the n quantity numbers in a sequence, then n non-negative numbers – elements of the sequence which module is not greater than 999.

output: changed sequence.

It seems I can't get what might be the problem

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <cmath>
//#include <climits>
#define SIZE 100000

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    int n, k, p;
    bool tag; tag = false;
    cin >> n;
    long long int *a = new long long int[n];
    long long int b[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { cin >> a[i]; }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { k = 0;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) { b[k] = j-k; k++; tag = true; }
        }
        if (tag) {
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) { 
                p = b[i];
                for (int i = p; i < n; i++) { a[i] = a[i + 1]; }
                n--;
            }
            tag = false;
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { cout << a[i] << " "; }
    return 0;
}
```

Input: 6 1 2 2 4 3 4    Output: 1 2 4 3

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935662/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-array

Comment: Since the limit of n is up to 100000, you cannot solve them in O(n*n) complexity. you need to solve them in O(nlogn) or in O(n)  to avoid Time Limit Exceeded (TLE)

Answer (score 1):

You can use unordered_set and vector

```
int n; cin >> n;
long long int x;
unordered_set<long long int>myset;
vector<long long int>v1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin>>x;
    if(myset.find(x)==myset.end())
    {
        myset.insert(x);
        v1.push_back(x);
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<v1.size();i++)
{
    cout<<v1[i]<<" ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use in you advantage the fact that input values are in the range from `0 to 999`.
A simple `bool used[1000]{}` could be used to flag if the current value has been used already before pushing it to `cout`, thus ensuring both `O(n)` complexity and limited memory usage (1000 bytes for the bool[]}.

Here's a sample solution around this idea:

```
#include<iostream>

#define MAX_VALUE 999

using namespace std;

int main() {
  freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
  freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

  bool used[MAX_VALUE + 1]{};

  size_t n;
  cin >> n;

  for (size_t num, i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cin >> num;

    if (!used[num]) {
      cout << num << " ";
      used[num] = true;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, though, why did you add max_value +1. 1 for what? what is the difference between bool used[size]{} and bool used[size] = {false}.

Comment: @V_head There are 1000 valid values - from 0 to 999 (inclusive), while the max valid value is `999`. `used[999]` will create an array with 999 elements with indexes from `0 to 998`, which is one less than `999`, so we have to add the missing one.

Comment: Thanks, about the difference?

Comment: @V_head First uses `direct-list-initialization` while the second uses `copy-list-initialization`. In this particular case both work the same and create arrays with all elements initialized to `false`. Note that `used[size] = {false}` sets explicitly to `false` just the first element while the rest are initialized with default values (which is `false` for `bool`). More on `direct-list-initialization vs copy-list-initialization`: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582981/forms-of-list-initialization)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of O(n) complexity. Your solution may exceed time-limit ( if it is low )

```
bool check[2000];
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) check[i] = 0; 

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  cin >> a[i];

  // +999 to avoid negative numbers
  check[a[i] + 999] = 1;
}

bool isPrint = false;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

  if (check[a[i] + 999]) {

    // mark false if already printed 
    check[a[i] + 999] = 0;

    if (isPrint) printf(" ");
    printf("%d", a[i]);

    isPrint = true;

  }

}
```

Comment: but you set isPrint to False, how re you going to print for first input?

Comment: it is for the space , not the number . For the first number , no need to print space before it . Otherwise print a space before subsequent numbers .

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a second array of unique numbers as you go.  I will demonstrate with a vector for the sake of simplicity.

```
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), arr[i]) == v.end()) {
            v.push_back(arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

Then, you just write the contents of the vector to the output file.

Comment: While valid in principle, this solution's complexity is not very optimal (in the worst case scenario for every number after the first 1000, a vector of 1000 elements should be traversed first).

Comment: @MartinBG Would it be more efficient if you stored the unique numbers in two places: a vector to maintain their original order, and an ordered set?  Then, in order to determine the uniqueness of subsequent numbers, you could check the ordered set instead of the vector.  My thinking being that operations on ordered sets are more efficient than those on un-ordered structures.  I appreciate the feedback btw.

Comment: Yes, storing unique values into a `set` for lookup will improve the solution (from up to `1000` down to most `10` comparisons on each number validation).  `unordered_set` is a better choice here as its lookup complexity is `Constant on average, worst case linear in the size of the container` compared to `O(log(n))` of the ordered `set`. As a side note, for this particular task even a [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) could be used to flag used numbers (use number value as index 0-999) - it acts as a bool array.